# Comparing Date and Time Values Taken from Now() Function

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table that users can log their use of a laboratory instrument. For the most basic function of logging current use, I have an error check that goes through a column that references the start and end times of the instrument use.

Basically, I want to compare the current time and the end time of the instrument use with previously submitted reservations/current instrument use. If the code detects that the current user input would interfere with a reservation, it changes the string value of **`"strCheckTime"`** from **`"ok"`** to **`"error"`**.

Then a If Then statement later on registers that and prompts the user with a message box.

The code is listed below.

So far, I have not gotten it to work. No matter what Now() returns and what reservations are currently present, it will run through the If Then statement and change the string value of **`"strCheckTime"`** from **`"ok"`** to **`"error"`**.

Any help would be most welcome!

```
'Defines and sets variables for current use/reservation check
Dim shtInstrument As Worksheet
Set shtInstrument = Worksheets(strShtName)
shtInstrument.Activate
Dim intCountEntries As Integer
intCountEntries = shtInstrument.Cells(shtInstrument.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Dim CurrentTime As Date
Dim StartDate As Date
Dim StartTime As Date
Dim EndDate As Date
Dim EndTime As Date
Dim rngStart As Range
Dim rngEnd As Range
Dim strCheckTime As String
strCheckTime = "Ok"

'Checks if desired instrument use falls in time frame of current use or reservation

For Each rngStart In shtInstrument.Range("H9:H" & intCountEntries)
StartDate = DateValue(rngStart.Value)
StartTime = TimeValue(rngStart.Value)
EndDate = DateValue(rngStart.Offset(0, 1).Value)
EndTime = TimeValue(rngStart.Offset(0, 1).Value)
If StartDate <= Date <= EndDate Then
    If StartTime <= Now() <= EndTime Then
        strCheckTime = "Error"
    ElseIf StartTime <= CurrentTime + TimeSerial(0, txtSample.Text * txtTime.Text, 0) <= EndTime Then
        strCheckTime = "Error"
    Else
        strCheckTime = "Ok"
    End If
Else
    'Do nothing
End If
Next rngStart
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
 If StartTime <= Now() <= EndTime Then
```

The function "Now()" returns the entire date, including the time.  This value is inherently always greater than the StartTime variable which represents only a time.

The second problem (that you figured out and mentioned in a comment) is that you can't use the equality operators like this.

The statement:

```
  If x <= y <= z
```

will be evaluated as such:

```
  If (x <= y) <= z
```

So this will be evaluated to:

```
  If (TRUE/FALSE) <= z Then
```

But TRUE = -1 and FALSE = 0 so as long as z is bigger than z (which in your case it always is), your function will return true.  You need to split the statements (again, per your comment).

You need to use either:

```
If StartTime <= Time() AND Time() <= EndTime Then
```

or

```
 If StartTime <= TimeValue(Now()) AND TimeValue(Now()) <= EndTime Then
```

Better yet, you don't need to use the Date and Time separately:

```
StartTime = [cell where date and time are located]
EndTime = [cell where date and time are located]

If StartTime <= Now()  AND Now() <= EndTime Then 'both time variables are defined by both the date and time
```

Note that to figure out problems like this, it is best to use a line such as:

```
 debug.print StartTime
 debug.print Now()
 debug.print EndTime
 debug.print (StartTime <= Now() <= EndTime)
```

to pinpoint where the problem is.

One additional comment is that if you are using things such as the Time throughout code, the Time function is evaluated when the code runs.  So if you have a procedure that takes a bunch of time and at the beginning you check the time vs something and then at the end you use the Time/Date function to get the time to record somewhere, these values will be different.  The best way to prevent this is to create a variable at the beginning of the code (or wherever you want to check the time:

```
  currTime = Now()
```

and then use this variable throughout your code.  In this particular case, the difference will either be extremely negligible or nonexistent as the check is in the same line of code, but in other cases it could be an issue.

EDIT***To include the additional problem of not being able to use equalities like this.

Comment: Thanks for the debug.print advice! I cannot believe I did not know about that beforehand.

I tried out TimeValue(Now()), but it still did not work. The debug.print function showed that the If Then Statement was always reporting "True". Once I used the date/time together and changed the statedment to StartDate <= Now() And Now() <= EndDate, it started working.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't notice that.  I'll add an edit to reflect this issue.